# Python MySQL Parameterized Queries with date

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a sql query used in django where a parameter is a date:

```
query="select DT_ORA_INSERIMENTO from richieste where DT_ORA_INSERIMENTO=%s", datestart
```

but in this manner I receive the error:

```
not enough arguments for format string
```

it seems django don't substitute the value of the variable with his value (2017-09-02 00:00:00)..
what is wrong?

Comment: `query="select DT_ORA_INSERIMENTO from richieste where DT_ORA_INSERIMENTO='%s'", datestart`
Anyway substitution <> binding

Answer (score 0):

```
query="select DT_ORA_INSERIMENTO from richieste where DT_ORA_INSERIMENTO=%s"%datestart
```

Comment: As suggested I receive the error DatabaseError at /getdata/
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00' at line 1").

Comment: Sounds like datestart is formatted wrong. run "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM richieste" to find out how to format the dates